# Provide warning for specifically named PowerShell commands

Tags: powershell, warnings, global

Is it possible to configure a **PowerShell** session to warn me any time I run a specifically named command/function?

As an example (I'd like to get warnings every time I use a command that begins with ***"Set-"***):

```
       If I run a Get-foo command, it runs that command without warning.
       If I run a Set-foo command, then it provides a warning about changes being made.
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was down-voted (Perhaps the 'user responsibility' motivation?.  Please help me understand why at least :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `$PSDefaultParameterValues` variable to define defaults, and many `Set-` commands include a 'Confirm' parameter, or a 'WhatIf' parameter. You could do something like:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{
    "Set-*:Confirm"=$true
    "Set-*:WhatIf"=$true
}
```

The format for this is a hashtable, where the key is ":" and the value is the value that you want to set. Wildcards are permitted for cmdlet names, so you can apply the setting to all `Set-` cmdlets easily enough.

If you wanted to use 'WhatIf' you would simple have to run the command with `-WhatIf:$false` if you want the command to actually do things rather than just tell you what it would have done.

```
Get-Item C:\Temp\*.docx | Copy-Item -Dest "$home\desktop" -WhatIf:$false
```

See [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters_default_values?view=powershell-6) for more information about the topic.